# query mysql to find total value

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, window-functions

please help me.
imagine the table as bellow

```
id    name         date_join
1     joni        2020-01-01
2     dani        2020-01-01
3     fani        2020-01-02
4     rina        2020-01-02
5     budi        2020-01-02
6     john        2020-01-03
7     dita        2020-01-03
8     sani        2020-01-05
9     soni        2020-01-06
10    aple        2020-01-06
11    rita        2020-01-06
12    hari        2020-01-06
```

and I want to query and show result like this

```
dates            total_member
2020-01-01       2
2020-01-02       5
2020-01-03       7
2020-01-04       7
2020-01-05       8
2020-01-06       12
2020-01-07       12
```

I dont know how to write query to show result like that.
I used (date_join) as dates, count(id) and group by date(date_join) and the result not show like   that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, you can solve this with aggregation and a window sum:

```
select
    date_join,
    sum(count(*))) over(order by date_join) total_members
from mytable
group by date_join
order by date_join
```

Or even without aggregation:

```
select date_join, total_members
from (
    select 
        date_join,
        count(*) over(order by date_join, name) total_members,
        row_number() over(order by date, name desc) rn
    from mytable
) t
where rn = 1
order by date_join
```

---

In earlier versions, one option is to select the distinct dates and use a correlated subquery to get the running count:

```
select 
    date_join,
    (select count(*) from mytable t1 where t1.date_join <= t.date_join) total_members
from (select distinct date_join from mytable) t
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that would be pretty simple like this :

```
select date_join `dates`, count(*) `total_member` 
from yourtable 
group by date_join 
order by total_member asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate all the dates and then use aggregation:

```
select d.dte, sum(count(*)) over (order by d.dte)
from (select '2020-01-01' as dte union all
      select '2020-01-02' as dte union all
      select '2020-01-03' as dte union all
      select '2020-01-04' as dte union all
      select '2020-01-05' as dte union all
      select '2020-01-06' as dte union all
      select '2020-01-07' as dte 
     ) d left join
     t
     on d.dte <= t.date_join
group by d.dte;
```